# How to save a tensorflow checkpoint to S3 on Sagemaker? It throws OSError: Unable to create file

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using Amazon Sagemaker Studio to train my tensorflow custom model. The problem is that when I run `model.fil(callbacks=[...], ...)`, it won't save checkpoints to AWS S3 even though bucket exists and training data is retrieved from that. It throws

`OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 's3://mybucket/01-0.70.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)`

How would you let it work?

The container I'm using is python==3.8, tensorflow==2.6, CPU Optimized.

The relevant discussion is found here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13796

Comment: For me please try 

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
 os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
 print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

That is because checkpoints created for saved parameter values prevention create a folder directory, I experience the same then I created folder to prevent a causes.

Comment: Thanks but I want to save it in S3, which doesn't have directory structure.

Comment: I used once i am studying  if you select Ubuntu and AI + sounds packages or serverless there always have.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is probably not able to use s3 ARNs as files. Indeed S3 is not a file system, so most libraries & APIs written for POSIX-compliant file interaction will fail to read an S3 ARN. You have 2 options:

1. If you want to stay in SageMaker Studio, you need to write your checkpoint locally, then copy it later to S3 with an `s3 cp` or boto3 `upload_file`
2. Recommended option: do not train in a notebook, but train in an async, SageMaker Training job. This has multiple benefits from a cost, scalability, reproducibility and instrumentation standpoint. SageMaker Training has a checkpoint path connected to the S3 bucket of your choice. I suggest you write checkpoints in `/opt/ml/checkpoints/`, and in your SDK call you set `checkpoint_s3_uri=s3://mybucket/<add a job ID to have only files from this job>`

Read more about SageMaker managed checkpointing here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html